# How to do content negotiation for binary resource

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint, X, which spits out json like a charm. The same resource can be generated into a binary variant. X's endpoint is made by a viewset, and the binary version of X has its own endpoint with the help of the action-decorator.

```
class XViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = X.objects.all()
    serializer_class = XSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def binary(self, request, pk=None):
        x = self.get_object()
        binx = x.get_binary(FORMAT)
        ..
```

Obviously, `binary` will never spit out json. How do I get a hold of the negotiated FORMAT, and how do I tell django-rest-framework about the binary formats supported by `binary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return the binary data from the `ViewSet` but have a [custom renderer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers) converting it:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import BaseRenderer, JSONRenderer

class BinaryRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    format = 'bin'
    render_style = 'binary'
    charset = None

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        # Either use `data` or access the view via
        # the `renderer_context` 
        view = renderer_context['view']
        return view.get_object().get_binary()

class XViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = X.objects.all()
    serializer_class = XSerializer
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, BinaryRenderer)
```

Check out the documentation on [how the renderer is determined](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#how-the-renderer-is-determined).

Comment: It's only relevant for a single action in the viewset though, that's what I can't figure out. It might be easier to, instead of adding an action to the existing viewset, to add an APIView just for that endpoint. But mixing APIViews and ViewSets makes for messy routers/urls.py...

Comment: I've opened [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041760/) now that I know the words for what to ask for, thx.

Comment: I didn't need to override the render-method on the renderer at all. I save the file somewhere available on an url and use a redirect instead of data in the response. Finally, `../binary.someformat` works in addition to `../binary/`!