# How to connect a renderer to a specific endpoint in a viewset, and only that endpoint

Tags: django-rest-framework

The DRF documentation shows how to connect a renderer to an APIView, but not how to do it for a specific action in a ViewSet. Given:

```
class XViewSet(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = XSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def my_action(self, request, pk=None):
         ..
```

How do I set a specific renderer for `my_action`, that will not affect the other/default actions in the viewset?

I can make an APIView just for that action of course but that makes for a more messy urls.py

Comment: Here `renderer` in the sense, do you mean `serializer`?

Comment: Serializer, no. A renderer controls what formats an endpoint can deliver, and I need to deliver some non-serialized data, like a binary image. Here's the docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#how-the-renderer-is-determined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `action` takes any argument that can be a class attribute:

```
class XViewSet(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = XSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'], renderer_classes=[yourrenderer])
    def my_action(self, request, pk=None):
         ..
```

Comment: I think a documentation-PR lies in my future, so that some other poor soul need not depend on SO for this :)

Comment: looking forwarding to it :)